# What is this odorless water dripping from passenger side of car?

Tags: ac, water-leak

I have water coming out of a pipe under my 2010 Renault Grand Scenic.  There is not a smell to it. The water is coming from the passenger side and it is dripping from a wee rubber pipe.

Comment: Air conditioning condensate dump?

Comment: Barely possible to understand what's written, but it does seem like AC condensate.

Answer (score 5):

For the sake of having answers for questions, I agree with the comments, and believe this is just condensation coming from the air conditioner.

You know how water collects on the outside of a cold glass when its warm outside?  The same thing happens on the cold coil inside your AC system.  Some cars just have a hole in the firewall that the water drains out of, and others, like your car, have a little rubber drain tube.

Critical fluids in the car have a color and normally have some smell.  A clear, odorless liquid can really only be water and is of no concern.